# Exploring interesting or random Bitbucket repositories

Tags: user-interface, bitbucket

On GitHub there is an [Explore](https://github.com/explore) page (and [list of public repositories](https://github.com/repositories)), where users can explore new interesting, and not so interesting, repositories.

Is there is such page for Bitbucket? I found a post about the same [Explore](https://bitbucket.org/explore) page, but it now redirects to the repository search.

Where can a Bitbucket user go to seek some new, arbitrary (without some keywords) open repository?

Comment: News for the addition: http://blog.bitbucket.org/2011/04/27/discovering-new-projects-on-bitbucket/, but its weird that the page was removed even without an announcement...

Comment: @Hydra: Yes, I was talking about this news.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitbucket had an "Explore" page for some time, but when they [completely changed their design a few months ago](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/10/09/introducing-the-redesigned-bitbucket/), unfortunately they dropped the "Explore" page.

I was sad to see it disappear, because at that time, one of my projects was featured there (hand-picked by the Bitbucket team) and gained about 100 followers because of that.

Comment: Related issue: [browse/explore repos?](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4337/output-issue-in-explore-bb-4881).

Comment: That's from before the design change (July 2012, the design change was in October). [This issue here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4776/browse-explore-repos-bb-6044) was created right after the design change, and it wasn't the only one (see the duplicates in the comments below).